# Компиляция С++ под Linux

Tags: gcc, c++, linux

Cкачал Oracle Instant Client - файлики rpm, установил их в линуксе (у меня CentOS).

Пример лежит здесь: /usr/share/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64
Инслуды здесь: /usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64
Библиотеки здесь: /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64

Компилю:

```
gcc cdemo81.c -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64
```

Ошибки:

```
cdemo81.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `OCIEnvCreate'
cdemo81.c:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `OCIHandleAlloc'
cdemo81.c:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `OCIHandleAlloc'

gcc cdemo81.c -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -lociei
```

Не может найти такую библиотеку... В каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: 1. Определитесь, у Вас с или с++.  
2. Возможно, библиотеки для другой разрядности.  
3. Можно посмотреть, есть ли в нужных библиотеках нужные функции (`nm имябиблиотеки | grep OCIHandleAlloc`).

Comment: 1) c++ конечно! 2) Нашел в либе libocci вроде как, выдаёт следующее теперь: /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client/lib/libocci.so when searching for -locci

Comment: Расширение файла .c, компилируем gcc... поэтому оно компилируется как си код. Используйте плюсовые расширения или, хотя бы g++.

Answer (score 2):

ответ из комментариев:

Расширение файла `.c`, компилируем `gcc`, поэтому оно компилируется *как си код*.

Используйте плюсовые расширения или, хотя бы `g++`.

Comment: +1 отвеченный вопрос, малой ценой)

Comment: Ответ в стиле: alexander barakin решил на stackoverflow подзаработать очки - лишь бы написать что-нибудь похожее)))

Comment: @sitev_ru: это общий ответ, Александр за него ничего не получит. Кстати, примите ответ, если не трудно. Цель – сделать ваш вопрос отвеченным, чтобы статистику поправить. Подробнее тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/956/181472

Comment: Зачем его принимать? Ответ вообще не правильный! Дело же тут совсем не в Си и С++... Дело было в оракловских библиотеках...

Comment: @sitev_ru, так напишите правильный ответ. через два дня движок даст вам возможность отметить его принятым.